# How to get first couple elements and remainder?

Tags: python, syntax, python-2.x

Is it possible to do something like this in Python:

```
a, b, *c = [1,2,3,4]
```

where

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = [3,4]
```

?

The most compact way I found of doing it is:

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
a, b = l[:2]
c = l[2:]
```

Comment: This is precisely the behavior of Python 3, see [PEP 3132](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).

Comment: Python 2 one-liner is `(a, b), c = l[:2], l[2:]`, which works only if `len(l)>=2`.

Comment: @Bo102010: Oh! Hah! I tried it in 2.x thinking this would be logical syntax for it, but it didn't work :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [DSM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15992190/722121) states, in 3.x your psuedocode works fine. A more general approach in 2.x is:

```
x = iter(rhs)
a, b, c = next(x), next(x), list(x)
```

This has the advantage of working with all iterables, not just sequences, and so is closer to the 3.x behaviour.

Edit: DSM's answer was deleted for some reason, but it stated that in 3.x, `a, b, *c = rhs` is perfectly valid code, producing the desired result.